# How to get memory size of variable?

Tags: memory-management, go, runtime

Does anybody know how to get memory size of the variable (`int`, `string`, `[]struct`, etc) and print it? Is it possible?

```
var i int = 1
//I want to get something like this:
fmt.Println("Size of i is: %?", i)
//Also, it would be nice if I could store the value into a string
```

Comment: reflect.TypeOf( i ).Size()

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use the [unsafe.Sizeof](https://godoc.org/unsafe#Sizeof) function for this.
It returns the size in bytes, occupied by the value you pass into it.
Here's [a working example](http://play.golang.org/p/ZqeA6OaaCi):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    a := int(123)
    b := int64(123)
    c := "foo"
    d := struct {
        FieldA float32
        FieldB string
    }{0, "bar"}

    fmt.Printf("a: %T, %d\n", a, unsafe.Sizeof(a))
    fmt.Printf("b: %T, %d\n", b, unsafe.Sizeof(b))
    fmt.Printf("c: %T, %d\n", c, unsafe.Sizeof(c))
    fmt.Printf("d: %T, %d\n", d, unsafe.Sizeof(d))
}
```

Take note that some platforms explicitly disallow the use of unsafe, because it is.. well, unsafe. This used to include AppEngine. Not sure if that is still the case today, but I imagine so.

As @Timur Fayzrakhmanov notes, `reflect.TypeOf(variable).Size()` will give you the same information. For the `reflect` package, the same restriction goes as for the `unsafe` package. I.e.: some platforms may not allow its use.

Comment: What if I have `x := make([][256]byte, 8, 16)` and I want to know the byte size of `x`? `unsafe.Sizeof(x)` will just return 12, no matter how many bytes are allocated.

Comment: @Hubro, the 12 bytes you are seeing is that of the `reflect.SliceHeader` type. Which is what you are creating with that expression. Counting the real size needs some manual work. E.g.: https://play.golang.org/p/o5ejsmWren  (very naive proof of concept)

Comment: I think this is incorrect, `unsafe.Sizeof` returns the size of the header of slices and strings, which is just a pointer and a length (plus cap for slices). That will be a constant size. The question is about the memory usage of the value.

Answer (score 21):

You can do it with either [`unsafe.Sizeof()`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof), or [`reflect.Type.Size()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type)

Answer (score 7):

The size of a variable can be determined by using `unsafe.Sizeof(a)`. The result will remain the same for a given type (i.e. `int`, `int64`, `string`, `struct` etc), irrespective of the value it holds. However, for type `string`, you may be interested in the size of the string that the variable references, and this is determined by using `len(a)` function on a given string. The following snippet illustrates that size of a variable of type string is always 8 but the length of a string that a variable references can vary:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    s1 := "foo"
    s2 := "foobar"

    fmt.Printf("s1 size: %T, %d\n", s1, unsafe.Sizeof(s1))
    fmt.Printf("s2 size: %T, %d\n", s2, unsafe.Sizeof(s2))
    fmt.Printf("s1 len: %T, %d\n", s1, len(s1))
    fmt.Printf("s2 len: %T, %d\n", s2, len(s2))
}
```

Output:

```
s1 size: string, 8
s2 size: string, 8
s1 len: string, 3
s2 len: string, 6
```

The last part of your question is about assigning the length (i.e. an `int` value) to a `string`. This can be done by `s := strconv.Itoa(i)` where `i` is an `int` variable and the `string` returned by the function is assigned to `s`.

Note: the name of the converter function is [`Itoa`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa), possibly a short form for Integer to ASCII. Most Golang programmers are likely to misread the function name as `Iota`.

Comment: "size of a variable of type string is always 8". No, the size of the string descriptor is either 8 or 16 bytes. For example, `s1 size: string, 16` and `s2 size: string, 16`.

Comment: "Most Golang programmers are likely to misread the function name [`strconv.Itoa`] as `Iota`." Not likely, "Within a constant declaration, the predeclared identifier [iota](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota) represents successive untyped integer constants."

Answer (score 7):

I've written a package which calculates the actual memory size consumed by variable at runtime: https://github.com/DmitriyVTitov/size
It has single function, so basic usage is:

`fmt.Println(size.Of(varName))`